# Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?

Tags: php, debug

Venho a muito tempo usando apenas:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

Para depurar os scripts (note que uso o `E_STRICT` apenas para manter compatibilidade com versões mais antigas do PHP), mas notei que em outras pessoas costumam usar o:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Ou quando vão desligar os erros:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

Eu sei que o `display_startup_errors` é `false` (ou 0) por padrão e ele se refere a exibir os erros como extensões que não foram carregadas, o problema é que até aonde teste `display_errors=0` e `error_reporting(0);` tem praticamente o mesmo efeito.

As minha duvida são:

- É necessário usar o `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`?
- O `error_reporting(0);` já não é o suficiente?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

A diretiva [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) simplesmente é um liga-desliga da exibição dos erros na saída do script.

Esta diretiva não muda o que é gravado nos logs do PHP. Só altera a saída gerada.

O ideal em servidores de produção é ela estar `false` no php.ini, para não dar detalhes dos problemas dos seus scripts para os usuários comuns.

Entretanto, **ocasionalmente** você precisa testar um único *script*, e aí usa isso:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

A diferença de por no *script* a ser testado, é que não afeta o resto do site/aplicação. E depois de debugado o código, basta remover a linha.

**Resumo:**

- Em produção, você seta o [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) para `false` direto no php.ini, e não muda isso , a não ser ocasionalmente, para *debugar* um script, e isso se não puder fazer o teste num servidor de desenvolvimento.

  Importante depois de resolvido o problema, tirar do PHP a exceção.

  Se estiver numa situação onde não tem acesso ao php.ini na produção, e o [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) estiver ligado, tem duas saídas, nesta ordem de preferência:

  1. trocar de hospedagem, OU
  2. usar o `ini_set` para desativar em todas as páginas, ou num *include* usado em todas.
- No desenvolvimento: deixe o [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) do php.ini em true, assim não precisa fazer mais nada em lugar nenhum.

### [display_startup_errors](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors)

Basicamente, esta configuração é similar ao [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), mas se refere aos erros ocorridos durante o processo de inicialização do PHP, e não à execução do script.

Mais ainda do que o ítem anterior, é preferencial que fique desabilitado, e só seja ligado para *debug* de alguma coisa mais séria que não foi identificada por outros meios. Para problemas normais no seu *script*, o [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) já basta.

### [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Aqui estamos falando de outro tipo de coisa. O [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) serve para você definir que tipo de erros vai exibir e logar.

Normalmente, em desenvolvimento, o ideal é deixar `E_ALL`, assim verá os erros e os *warnings* sobre uma diversidade de coisas que pode dar problema no código atual e no código futuro.

Talvez, em produção, o E_ALL seja um pouco de exagero, mas deixar zero pode simplesmente esconder algum problema que você não tenha percebido no desenvolvimento. Aviso sobre coisas obsoletas talvez não sejam importantes em produção, mas esconder tudo dificilmente é desejável.

Note que é importante ler a documentação do PHP, pois por incrível que pareça, o `E_ALL` só mostra realmente todos os erros nas versões mais novas.

**Principais opções:**

```
E_ALL           Todos os erros e alertas (Cuidado. Veja o E_STRICT)
E_ERROR         Erros fatais em runtime
E_WARNING       Erros não fatais em runtime
E_PARSE         Erros de compilação (antes da execução do código)
E_DEPRECATED    Avisos de coisas obsoletas, que serão retiradas no futuro
E_NOTICE        Avisos que podem ou não ser bugs
E_STRICT        Dá recomendações de melhor interoperabilidade, desde o PHP 5.
                Note que o E_ALL só inclui o E_STRICT do 5.4 em diante
```

**Resumo:**

- Em produção, provavelmente uma boa combinação é:

  ```
  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
  ```

  notar que o `& ~` significa que estamos **desativando** aquela opção (é um `AND` binário de um `NOT` da *flag*).
- No desenvolvimento eu sugiro usar o `E_ALL | E_STRICT` e tudo o mais que tiver direito.

Answer (score 4):

Um complemento a resposta existente,

Dependendo do ambiente, `error_reporting();` ou `ini_set('display_errors', ..);` podem ser ignorados quando invocados em tempo de execução.

Falando de forma mais simples, há servidores de hospedagem que não permitem que essas configurações sejam feitas pelo PHP ou htaccess. Normalmente nesses casos oferecem um painel administrativo específico para setar as configurações. Por isso, é comum ver muitos usuários PHP que configuram em tempo de execução e reclamam de que o script "não funciona".

Nesses casos não há muito o que fazer. Deve-se usar os recursos do provedor de hospedagem.

Uma nota relevante é que o PHP 7 tornou obsoleto diversos recursos marcados como `DEPRECATED` e também modificou o nível de mensagens de erro para determinadas execuções que até então estavam emitindo como `E_STRICT`.

Exemplo

```
class Foo
{
    Bar(){}
}
```

Isso não é permitido desde a versão 5.4, se não me engano. Desde essa versão, vem sendo emitido o erro no nível `E_STRICT`.

Para "resolver", ocultamos esse nível de erro pela função `error_reporting()` ou `ini_set()`. Todavia, isso já não é mais possível no PHP7, pois é emitido `Fatal Error`.

Por isso, ocultar erros do nível `E_STRICT` é uma escolha que deve ser feita com cautela. Só aplique quando for mesmo necessário. Normalmente aplicamos em sistemas legados onde é inviável corrigir tudo a tempo hábil.

No caso do exemplo acima, o PHP, desde a vesão 5.4, pede para que os métodos e propriedades de classes tenham definição explícita de visibilidade.

Exemplo para evitar o erro STRICT (php5.4~5.6) ou FATAL ERROR (php7)

```
class Foo
{
    public Bar(){}
}
```

Obviamente isso também afeta "violações" que até então eram permitidas.

```
class Foo
{
    public static Bar(){}
    public Other(){}
}

/**
Acessando de forma estática um método não estático.
*/
Foo::Other();
```

Isso gera um erro nível `STRICT` a partir do PHP 5.4. Esse erro, conforme mencionado acima, pode ser ocultado e assim "resolvemos" o problema. Na verdade estamos escondendo a sujeira para debaixo do tapete.

No PHP7 isso também deixou de ser do nível `STRICT` e é emitido `FATAL ERROR`.

O exemplo acima com as classes é pequeno pois há diversas mudanças no PHP7.

A recomendação é sempre resolver todo tipo de erro a nível `E_STRICT` e mesmo os mais simples do tipo `E_NOTICE`. Por isso, no ambiente de desenvolvimento deve-se manter ativo todos os níveis de erro. E, obviamente, no ambiente de produção é recomendável ocultar os erros de serem exibidos publicamente. O usuário comum não precisa saber detalhes de erros até porque isso também implica em falha de segurança pois expõe informações a pessoas má intencionadas.