# Por quê os erros em scripts PHP executados via linha de comando não aparecem no log de erros do apache?

Tags: php, log, linha-de-comando, recuperação-de-erros

É importante observar que os erros que ocorrem em execução de script PHP via browser são registrados sem qualquer problema no arquivo: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

O problema só acontece quando os scripts são executados via linha de comando.

A sequencia que realizei é a seguinte:

1 - Limpar arquivo de log de erros do Apache:

```
root@debian:/# echo > /var/log/apache2/error.log
root@debian:/#
```

2 - Testar se o arquivo de log do Apache realmente foi limpo:

```
root@debian:/# cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

root@debian:/#
```

Ok - O arquivo está vazio.

3 - Execução de um script PHP via linha de comando:

```
root@debian:/#php script.php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setWhere() on null in /var/www/html/script.php on line 38
root@debian:/#
```

4 - Consultar o arquivo de log do Apache:

```
root@debian:/# cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

root@debian:/#
```

O problema: o arquivo de log continua vazio.

**Minha dúvida:** Por quê os erros em scripts PHP executados via linha de comando não aparecem (ou não estão aparecendo) no log de erros do apache? Como é possível logar estes erros no referido arquivo (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`)?

Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Um fato é que pela linha de comando você não estará passando pelo Apache, por si só ja é de se esperar que o Apache não vá logar os erros do PHP.

A diretiva do `php.ini` que controla o caminho do *log* de erros é essa:

```
error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log
```

Vale lembrar que, mesmo com tudo configurado no PHP para logar as coisas que você precisa, nada garante que o PHP da linha de comando esteja usando o mesmo `php.ini`.

De acordo com o [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.options.php), caso queira determinar no momento da execução qual é o `.ini` a ser usado, você tem a diretiva `-c <path>|<file>`. Exemplo:

```
php -c /etc/php/custom.ini meuscript.php
```

Dependendo do que quer fazer, basta usar a redireção do shell:

```
php meuscript.php 1> out.log 2> error.log
```

Um ponto importante em qualquer dos caminhos escolhidos é ter a certeza que o usuário que está executando o PHP pela linha de comando tenha permissão para escrever no referido arquivo de log. (e espero que você esteja usando o `root` apenas para testes e numa máquina que não seja de produção).

Esta postagem tem umas coisas que podem ajudar no *fine tuning* das configurações:

> [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106562/por-que-usar-error-reporting-com-display-errors-e-display-startup-errors)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente: php -c /etc/php/custom.ini meuscript.php

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Se for automatizar o seu PHP, lembre-se de garantir que o usuário da crontab ou do script que chama o PHP tenha acesso ao arquivo.