# Problema ao usar a biblioteca hashid.id

Tags: php

Estou tentando implementar a biblioteca [hashids](http://hashids.org/php/) no meu projeto, não estou usando o `composer`

Minha função é simples assim:

```
function generate_hash_id($id){
    require("../libs/Hashids.php");
    $hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('teste');
    $hash = $hashids->encrypt($id);
    return $hash;
}
```

Porém está retornando `500 Internal Server Error`

Chamo a função dentro de um iterator

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10, $i++){
    generate_hash_id($i);
}
```

A estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que entendi está acusando que a biblioteca não está nesse `path`, mas o caminho é esse mesmo!

---

Seguindo as dicas do @guilherme, retirei o `require` de dentro da `function`.

```
require("../libs/Hashids.php");

function generate_hash_id($id){
    $hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('teste');
    $hash = $hashids->encrypt($id);
    return $hash;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 10, $i++){
    generate_hash_id($i);
}
```

Agora o erro que retorna:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Hashids\Hashids::encrypt() in /usr/share/nginx/www/api/automatic/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/www/api/automatic/index.php(110): generate_hash_id(1) #1 {main} thrown in /usr/share/nginx/www/api/automatic/index.php on line 16

---

Comment: Amigo troque require por require_once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você chama mais de uma vez o `require` ele vai causar algum erro de exceção porque a função já foi declarada na primeira vez que chamou o `require '../libs/Hashids.php';`, se chamar de novo (no teu caso o loop) ele vai tentar declarar de novo e nisto é que ocorre o erro.

Como você deve estar com os erros desligados aparece 500 Internal error server, para corrigir troque o require por `require_once`, outra coisa o método `$hashids->encrypt` não existe, o correto é `$hashids->encode`, veja: https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php/blob/master/lib/Hashids/Hashids.php#L114

O código correto seria:

```
function generate_hash_id($id){
    require_once "../libs/Hashids.php";
    $hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('teste');
    $hash = $hashids->encode($id);
    return $hash;
}
```

Para detalhes de como detectar erros e como usar em modo de produção e desenvolvimento leia esta pergunta e respostas:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Comment: Unnn na verdade eu puxei o `require("../libs/Hashids.php")`; para fora da função, porém to tendo instabilidade aqui no servidor, então ainda não consegui testar todas as recomendações rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio mas `require_once` resolveu? Ou ocorre erro ainda? Se for tipo locaweb nem tem muito o que configurar :/, todavia eu digo que vc deve fazer tudo na tua maquina, testar bem, usar o `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` no topo do documento e depois que tudo estiver ok ae sim enviar para o servidor de produção seguindo as dicas de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106563/3635

Comment: o `require_once` resolveu o problema inicial, mas agora o erro que retorna é outro rs

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio e você vai me dizer qual é? :) assim posso ajudar

Comment: já editei na pergunta :)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio troca `encrypt` por `encode` e me diz o que ocorre. Editei a resposta ;)

Comment: Juro que eu não estou louco e na hora que peguei esse código como referencia estava `encrypt` ahsuashausahs, agora fui ver na documentação dos caras e é `encode`, funcionou @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado :)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio por isso que sempre olho o site oficial e vou desde a página inicial, teve vez que fui pesquisar sobre Laravel através do google e eu ia parar na página da documentação do Laravel4 hehehehe, XD mas eu uso o 5.2/5.3