# Estou tentando enviar e-mail com HTML e PHP e não consigo

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Bom, é o seguinte, criei um formulário para enviar um orçamento do cliente do meu cliente para o meu cliente utilizando o site, porém não clica no botão "enviar" nada acontece e não estou entendendo o porquê. Vou deixar o HTML e o PHP aqui na descrição, lá vai:

HTML:

```
<form name="orcamento" action="mail.php">           
            <div id="form-main">
                <div id="form-div">
                    <form class="form" id="form1" method="POST" action="mail.php">
                        <p class="name">
                            <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Nome" id="name" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="email">
                            <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="phone">
                            <input name="tel" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone (Com DDD)" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="text">
                            <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Produtos"></textarea>
                        </p>

                        <div class="submit">
                            <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdIgR4UAAAAALrbj6sHWoRU6v9zZgDXp71MXQiX" data-callback='onSubmit' name="enviar" type="submit" id="button-blue" formmethod="POST"> ENVIAR </button>
                                <div class="ease"></div>
                                <div class="g-recaptcha"
                                    data-sitekey="6LdIgR4UAAAAALrbj6sHWoRU6v9zZgDXp71MXQiX"
                                    data-callback="onSubmit"
                                    data-size="invisible">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST['name'] & $_POST['text'] & $_POST['tel'] != ''){
    include "classes/class.phpmailer.php";
    $GetPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $mensagem = "<html><head><center><img src=\"image/logo-grande.png\"></center></head><body style=\"background-color:#FFF;font-family:Segoe UI;font-site:14px;color:#000;\">
        <br /><br />
        <b>Contato Site ".Config::tituloSite()."</b>
        <br /><br />
        <hr style=\"width:100%;border:1px solid #3399CC\" /><br />
        <b>Nome:</b> ".$_POST['name']."<br /><br />
        <b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST['email']."<br /><br />
        <b>Telefone:</b> ".$_POST['tel']."<br /><br />
        <b>Mensagem:</b> ".nl2br($_POST['text'])."<br /><br />
        <hr style=\"width:100%;border:1px solid #3399CC\" />
        </body></html>";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Charset = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $mail->Host = 'mail.madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
    $mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

     //Define o remetente
     // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
    $mail->From = 'mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; 
    $mail->FromName = "ORÇAMENTO-SITE";

     //Define os destinatário(s)
    $mail->AddAddress('joaolbrocha@gmail.com');         
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Contato pelo site - {$_POST['name']}".date("H:i")." - ".date("d/m/Y");
    $mail->Body = $mensagem;

    if($mail->Send()){  
        echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';

    }
    else{
        echo 'Houve algum erro no envio. Tente novamente!'; .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}?>
```

Comment: para que serve dois forms <form name="orcamento" action="mail.php">

Comment: Era pra teste mas não faz nenhuma diferença com ou sem

Comment: está funcionando agora? vc recebeu um mail que fiz aqui para teste com seu código corrigido?

Comment: Recebi sim, Léo, mas no teste que fiz direto no site não, recebi agora, faz 2 mins

Comment: uai, mas a resposta do Guilherme Nascimento  está marcada como aceita, dai pensei que já tinha acertado.

Comment: Dei aceita pois o erro do && não era o que eu estava perguntando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua linha 43 esta errada, tem um `;` antes do `.`:

```
echo 'Houve algum erro no envio. Tente novamente!'; .$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

O que gera um erro como:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in enviar.php on line 43

O correto seria isto:

```
echo 'Houve algum erro no envio. Tente novamente!' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
```

Provavelmente o erro não aparece porque no `php.ini` deve estar assim:

```
display_errors=Off
```

Leia mais sobre erros em:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

---

### Nota sobre a página

Ao abrir o link da página com o console do browser logo é possivel notar a falta do Jquery

[image: erro]

E no código fonte vc adicionou jQuery duas vezes:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
```

O primeiro:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
```

Esta causando erro 404, remova-o, ou então remova o segundo e ajuste o link do script de `"js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"` para `"/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"`, ficando assim:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
```

Outro detalhe no PHP é como o Leo disse, você usou `&` ao invés de `&&`, troque isto:

```
if($_POST['name'] & $_POST['text'] & $_POST['tel'] != ''){
```

Por isto

```
if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['text'] && $_POST['tel'] != ''){
```

### Leia sobre os operadores na documentação do PHP

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.php

Comment: Então mas o problema principal é que não está acontecendo nada quando clica no submit, faça o teste vc mesmo: www.madeireirapadroeira.com.br/novo-site e tente fazer um orçamento de qualquer coisa, não chega nada no meu e-mail e tbm não acontece nada quando clica no submit

Comment: Me desculpe, eu tentei descrever o problema de um jeito mas não consegui fazer com que você entendesse. Vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Não leva a mal, não é questão de "eu" entender amigo, a questão é "você" entender, vc nem citou o uso de Ajax e jQuery, o código como esta na pergunta nem chega perto de ser semelhante ao do site, veja como esta com falha na inclusão do jQuery: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFlmH.png

Comment: Muito obrigado e me desculpe também pois sou iniciante na área, faz 1 mês que estou trabalhando na área, por isso aconteceu esses erros bobos, sei que são bobos pois programo um pouco em C#. Mas na área web faz 1 mês que venho conhecendo. Pois bem, agradeço pela "bronca" kkkkkk agora pelo menos abriu o arquivo "mail.php". Mas ainda preciso saber como envia o e-mail pois ainda não enviou o e-mail mas abriu o arquivo mail.php. Teria como você me ajudar?

Comment: Sim, corrigi, vou colocar no ar para você dar uma olhada, ok?

Comment: pronto, sem problemas no console e arquivos no ar em www.madeireirapadroeira.com.br/novo-site

Comment: Opa, é mesmo, me desculpe, esqueci de corrigir este erro... Acabei de corrigir e deu um erro que está faltando a classe smtp.phpmailer.php e estou a colocando agora mesmo, peraê...

Comment: @JoãoRocha o erro `Function eregi() is deprecated` quer dizer que vc esta usando uma versão antiga do phpmailer, recomendo que atualize ela.

Comment: Eu tentei, cara, mas não deu certo não :/

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso e mesmo assim deu isso: Esta página não está funcionando

madeireirapadroeira.com.br não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.

Comment: Não tirei, não mexi nele, apenas no phpMailer

Comment: @JoãoRocha manda o conteudo do mail.php no pastebin.com pra mim por favor.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GCBFEzAd

Comment: @JoãoRocha tome cuidado ao digitar no PHP, vc esta confundindo apostrofos com aspas, isso é o basico do php, variaveis dentro de apostros não acessam as variaveis: `$mail->Subject = 'Contato pelo site - {$_POST['name']}".date("H:i")." - ".date("d/m/Y")';
    $mail->Body    = '$mensagem';
    $mail->AltBody = '$mensagem';`, segue o código corrigido: https://pastebin.com/raw/wF5GnFGM

Comment: Continua dando 

Esta página não está funcionando

madeireirapadroeira.com.br não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

eu copiei e colei seu código alterando apenas a senha

Comment: @JoãoRocha tem certeza que subiu o arquivo correta para o servidor? No teu localhost (wamp, xampp, easyphp ou linux) ocorre o erro?

Comment: Tenho sim, no localhost dá um erro na linha 37 - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\Mad-Pad\mail.php on line 37
 e é isso que tem na linha 37 - //$mail->AddAddress('destinatario2@dominio.com', 'Nome do Destinatário');

Comment: @JoãoRocha a tua linha 37 esta diferente da linha 37 do https://pastebin.com/raw/wF5GnFGM, copia e cola novamente por favor, vc deve ter acidentalmente confundido os arquivos ou edições. Testa primeiro no localhost

Comment: Desculpe, confundi as botas kkkkkk, está dando erro é na linha 20 que é a linha que está estanciando as classes -  $mail = new PHPMailer;

Comment: @JoãoRocha vc copiou "exatamente" como eu lhe mandei o código? Se o erro é na linha 20 poderia mandar "qual" a mensagem de erro agora? Amigo entenda cada erro é um erro especifico dizer o "erro" é em tal lugar não significa que fará parte do mesmo erro, entendeu?

Comment: Depurando...
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::From() in /home/madeirei/public_html/novo-site/mail.php on line 32

Comment: Isso é o que aparece quando http://madeireirapadroeira.com.br/novo-site/mail.php

Comment: @JoãoRocha eu disse da outra vez, por favor presta atenção, eu disse que era pra adaptar "deste" código: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example, os métodos que vc usou no teu código são da versão antiga... Eu disse que teria que refazer com versão nova. Desculpa a sinceridade, mas por favor preste atenção na dicas ;) ... Corrija, não é `$mail->From('mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br');`, o correto é `$mail->setFrom('mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br');`

Comment: Tudo bem, me desculpe, é que enquanto eu estava aqui, eu estava alterando o código várias e várias vezes por estar fazendo pesquisas e ir alterando para fazer testes, e por isso dava cada hora um erro e cada hora estava um código diferente, me perdoe, foi erro meu

Comment: @JoãoRocha sem problemas ;) ... só estou lhe orientando e não dando bronca por mal, em programação vc deve ter atenção aos detalhes o máximo possivel e aprender a analisar os erros. Assim que terminar se falhar me avisa

Comment: Perdão por ter te deixado um pouco nervoso kkkkk. Ahh e a propósito, apareceu isso : Depurando...O seu orÃ§amento foi enviado para uma de nossas atendentes, por favor, aguarde o retorno em breve. Provavelmente enviou mas ainda não chegou na minha caixa de entradas, acredito que chegará em alguns minutos. Não tenho palavras pra te agradecer pela ajuda e por ter perdido um tempo e um pouco da paciencia cmg kkkkkk. Valeu de vdd!

Comment: Não fiquei nervoso @JoãoRocha, é que vc estava se atrapalhando muito sem necessidade, precisei ser mais firme contigo ;) ... Dá uma olhada na caixa de Spam (ou Mala_direta) no e-mail, as vezes pode ter caido lá a mensagem.

Comment: Acabou de cair aqui, é que demora um pouco para enviar (2 mins no max), acho que isso é normal, não é?

Comment: @JoãoRocha sim, tem e-mail que pode levar até uma hora, depende do fluxo de mensagens no servidor. Não tem nada haver com a parte PHP, é coisa lá no servidores IMAP e SMTP de transporte, nada que possamos fazer, depende do trafego mesmo, tipo "hora do rush" nas avenidas :)... Creio que agora todos os teus problemas tenham sido resolvidos né? Preciso ir indo, até a proxima.

Comment: Até a próxima, Guilherme, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

No HTML retirei o form que estava sobrando

```
<div id="form-main">
<div id="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Nome" id="name" />
        </p>
        <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </p>
        <p class="phone">
        <input name="tel" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone (Com DDD)" />
        </p>
        <p class="text">
        <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Produtos"></textarea>
        </p>
        <div class="submit">
        <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdIgR4UAAAAALrbj6sHWoRU6v9zZgDXp71MXQiX" data-callback='onSubmit' name="enviar" type="submit" id="button-blue" formmethod="POST"> ENVIAR </button>
            <div class="ease">
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdIgR4UAAAAALrbj6sHWoRU6v9zZgDXp71MXQiX" data-callback="onSubmit" data-size="invisible">
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP aqui estava dando erros e como pensei que você já tinha resolvido, deletei a pasta error_log. Portanto não lembro exatamente os erros.

> Um deles era no `$mail->Host = 'mail.madeireirapadroeira.com.br';`
> corrigi para `$mail->Host = 'smtp.madeireirapadroeira.com.br';`
>
> outro era Config::tituloSite() nessa linha `<b>Contato Site ".Config::tituloSite()."</b>` a qual retirei
>
> mais em `if($_POST['name'] & $_POST[....` que foi corrigido para `if($_POST['name'] && $_POST[ ....`
>
> observe tb que comentei `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` e `$mail->Port       = 587;` pois esses não são necessários no meu servidor. Não sei se no seu servidor são requeridos. Ai vc faça os devidos testes com e sem.

Segue o PHP o qual você recebeu o email enviado do meu servidor.

```
<?php
if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['text'] && $_POST['tel'] != ''){
    require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $GetPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST,FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $mensagem = "<html><head><center><img src=\"image/logo-grande.png\"></center></head><body style=\"background-color:#FFF;font-family:Segoe UI;font-site:14px;color:#000;\">
        <br /><br />
        <b>Contato Site</b>
        <br /><br />
        <hr style=\"width:100%;border:1px solid #3399CC\" /><br />
        <b>Nome:</b> ".$_POST['name']."<br /><br />
        <b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST['email']."<br /><br />
        <b>Telefone:</b> ".$_POST['tel']."<br /><br />
        <b>Mensagem:</b> ".nl2br($_POST['text'])."<br /><br />
        <hr style=\"width:100%;border:1px solid #3399CC\" />
        </body></html>";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Charset = "UTF-8";
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Username = 'leo@kithomepage.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
    //$mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
    $mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

     //Define o remetente
     // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
    $mail->From = 'mensageiro@madeireirapadroeira.com.br'; 
    $mail->FromName = "ORÇAMENTO-SITE";

     //Define os destinatário(s)
    $mail->AddAddress('joaolbrocha@gmail.com');        
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "Contato pelo site - {$_POST['name']}".date("H:i")." - ".date("d/m/Y");
    $mail->Body = $mensagem;

    if($mail->Send()){  
        echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';

    }
    else{
        echo 'Houve algum erro no envio. Tente novamente!' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Valeu, esse era um dos problemas...

Comment: Eu recebi o e-mail, Léo.