# Evitar notice em PHP display_error

Tags: php

Eu tenho este trecho de código, mas muitos outros que seguem o mesmo estilo:

```
if(!$_COOKIE[SITEINDEX]) {
    setcookie(SITEINDEX, max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))));
    define(siteindex, '/' . max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))) . '/');
} else {
    define(siteindex, '/' . $_COOKIE[SITEINDEX] . '/'); 
}
```

Ele faz com que ao carregar a página, crie um *cookie* com o primeiro URI da URL para que não fique mudando cada vez que aperta F5 ou tenha que refazer cada vez que aperta F5 e, neste caso, eu não posso atribuir valor algum para este *cookie* `siteindex` antes de acontecer o `if` ou ele não teria lógica e é ai que entra o problema. O PHP exibe *notices* *"siteindex" not defined* e impede de o aplicativo ser carregado, não só com este trecho, pois tenho `if` deste estilo em vários lugares, que não tem a variável declarada para ele saber se existe e, caso sim, efetuar algo, caso não, só mostrar, em servidores online que não tem `display_error` eles funcionam mas em localhost que tem `display_error` eles não funcionam. Não queria desligar o `dislay_error`, mas sim sanar isso sem declarar a variável com algum valor que vá impedir o funcionamento.

Como faria isso?

Um exemplo que da Notices é este

```
<?php
    define(siteprot, $_SERVER[HTTPS] ? 'https://' : 'http://');
    define(sitehost, $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);
    define(siteuri,  $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);

    if(!$_COOKIE[SITEINDEX]) {
        setcookie(SITEINDEX, max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))));
        define(siteindex, '/' . max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))) . '/');
    } else {
        define(siteindex, '/' . $_COOKIE[SITEINDEX] . '/'); }

    define(siteurl, siteprot . sitehost . siteindex);
    define(secret, '/' . max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))) . '/');
?>
```

> Notice: Use of undefined constant siteprot - assumed 'siteprot' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTPS - assumed 'HTTPS' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant sitehost - assumed 'sitehost' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant HTTP_HOST - assumed 'HTTP_HOST' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant siteuri - assumed 'siteuri' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 4
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant REQUEST_URI - assumed 'REQUEST_URI'
>   in D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line
>   4
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant SITEINDEX - assumed 'SITEINDEX' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: SITEINDEX in D:\Roberto
>   Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant SITEINDEX - assumed 'SITEINDEX' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PHP_SELF - assumed 'PHP_SELF' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 7
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server
>   57\www\qrcode\index.php:2) in D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server
>   57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant siteindex - assumed 'siteindex' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PHP_SELF - assumed 'PHP_SELF' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant siteurl - assumed 'siteurl' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant secret - assumed 'secret' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PHP_SELF - assumed 'PHP_SELF' in
>   D:\Roberto Monteiro\Desktop\Server 57\www\qrcode\index.php on line 13
>   /qrcode//qrcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro "`siteindex" not defined` acontece porque você não está verificando se essa variável foi declarada anteriormente. Com isso o PHP não reconhece o conteúdo dessa variável.

O que você pode fazer é verificar se ela existe, se não existir definir ela primeiramente:

```
if(!defined('SITEINDEX')){
   define("SITEINDEX","alguma coisa");
}
```

No seu caso, você precisa criar um cookie com nome fixo, pois senão o PHP não conseguirá detectar qual o valor de SITEINDEX:

```
if( empty($_COOKIE['SITEINDEX']) ) {
    setcookie('SITEINDEX', max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))));
    define('SITEINDEX', '/' . max(explode('/', dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]))) . '/'); 
} else {
    define('SITEINDEX', '/' . $_COOKIE['SITEINDEX'] . '/'); }
}
```

Com isso o PHP reconhecerá que quando não estiver definido o COOKIE na posição 'SITEINDEX' e o conteúdo estiver vazio, ele irá preencher corretamente e não deverá gerar o problema de definição de variável.

Manipulação de erros: Verifique esse [Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106563/57801)

Comment: é, eu sei que poderia trocar tudo para isset ou empty mas são mais de 60  mil linhas, eu troquei algumas e funciona muito bem, mas ai que está, eu não queria ter que voltar a usar uma coisa que parei de usar que é o empty e o isset, mas valew

Comment: adicionei um exemplo que da notices se ligar display error

Comment: na verdade funciona em qualquer versão do php atualmente estou na 7 mas estava na 5, é que com error desligado ele funciona mas ao ligar é que da erro, mas vou tentar com estes que você colocou

Comment: realmente, com estes (E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE) ele permitiu a execução do script sem exibir os notices, tem como não exibir apenas o notice ou preciso estipular todos que quero exibir menos o notice? pois quero ver todos os error menos os que não são exatamente um erro

Comment: Atualizei a resposta adicionando no final a parte da reportação de erro

Comment: legal legal só colocar o ^ nos que não desejar

Comment: não sei o porque, mas nos que usei só funcionou assim 
E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT

Comment: Acho melhor dar uma revisada nesta questão dos erros [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635) ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento linkei na resposta o outro Post

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Corrigido!

Comment: @Everson não é bem uma questão de correção é apenas uma dica de funcionalidade para simplificar algo, ambas formas são corretas :)

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na falta de aspas para delimitar strings.

```
define(siteprot, $_SERVER[HTTPS] ? 'https://' : 'http://');
define(sitehost, $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);
define(siteuri,  $_SERVER[REQUEST_U...
```

Deveria ser assim

```
define('siteprot', $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://');
define('sitehost', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('siteuri',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_U...
```

Deve corrigir isso em tudo. Exemplo

```
$_SERVER[PHP_SELF] // errado

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] // correto
```

Você ainda pode indagar, por que funcionava em outro ambiente?

A resposta é que o ambiente anterior estava mal configurado ou foi desativado de forma intencional e não necessariamente quer dizer que quem o fez não sabia o que estava fazendo.

O PHP, quando é configurado para omitir esses erros, automaticamente transforma a constante indefinida em string e, assim, mesmo com a semântica do código errada, tudo funciona sem problemas.

Se quer resolver rápido, basta desativar o warning desse nível de erro. Mas o recomendado é corrigir tudo delimitando com aspas.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Isso desativa os erros do tipo "notice" e de quebra desativa os tipos strict e deprecated.

Salientando, só use isso como solução se estiver em urgência e não tem tempo para corrigir tudo.