# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll

Tags: php

EU fiz uma entrevista pra uma vaga de estágio, e pediram pra fazer um CRUD com Codeigniter e mandar pra eles, fiz e testei de todas as formas, em casa e na faculdade funcionou, mandei pra eles e eles me retornaram um email mostrando esse erro na foto abaixo e eu não faço a minima ideia do que seja. 
EU agradeceria muito se alguém me ajudasse com isso...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu diria que o problema não é no seu código e sim na base onde testaram.

Comment: Então, em casa eu uso Windows, eu to achando que na empresa la eles usam Linux, so pode ser isso

Comment: Parece ter alguma linha configurada errada no php.ini que tenta chamar uma DLL no linux ... parece ser problema de ambiente. Solicite o php.ini deles ou peça para que executem em outro PC. Se tiver interesse [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/91) trata sobre as mensagens de erros do php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve estar em um sistema operacional Linux ou Mac OSX, as extensões `.dll` são para windows, então é provável que você tenha baixado manualmente, ela não vai funcionar.

A extensão PDO é nativa geralmente nas distros quando instala o PHP, então provavelmente você tem que abrir o php.ini e descomentar (tirar o `;`) destas linhas:

```
;extension=pdo.so
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

ficando assim:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Então reinicie o Apache (ou Nignix, ou lighttpd, depende de qual servidor HTTP usa).

Não esqueça de excluir a linha (deve ser algo semelhante, abra o php.ini e use `Ctrl`+`F` e procure por `.dll`):

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: Então, vou passar isso pra eles e espero que corrija.

Comment: @FranciscoMarcos você não tem acesso ao php.ini do servidor?

Comment: Pior que não, eu mandei projeto pra eles e só retornaram mandando o erro, nenhum arquivo

Comment: @FranciscoMarcos entendi, qualquer coisa copia o link da tua pergunta e manda pra eles :)

Comment: Vai ser o jeito mesmo rs.

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino se extensões que veem junto com pré-compilado não estiverem na pasta foi por algum erro absurdo, como o proprio usuário ter deletado manualmente e não deixa de ser uma pergunta OFF-TOPIC, isso mostra que você não entende o escopo do site Stack Overflow em Português, que esta disponivel no Help/Ajuda (veja no rodapé). A minha resposta é totalmente eficiente e o autor a marcou como correta pois mostra que resolveu o problema e que exatamente este era o problema (que expliquei na resposta)... Se a .dll não existe na pasta é porque algo de muito errado foi feito e não é comum.

Comment: @GilbertoAlbino fora que basta olhar o PATH do erro, o caminho é de um servidor LINUX ou unix-like, e ele tenteou carregar um .dll (que é windows) em um servidor não windows, ou seja algo de muito errado tinha no problema do autor da pergunta, ***isso com certeza não é um erro comum***