# Qual a Função do Error_reporting(0)

Tags: php

Qual é a função do código: `Error_reporting(0)`, eu sei que é para relatar um erro, e entre parenteses informar o nivel, porém na documentação do `PHP` não encontrei esse nivel 0.

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635) - Nota: tome cuidado, o error_reporting com zero pode não ser um bom caminho para isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error_reporting()` define quais tipos de erros serão exibidos, isso incluir warnings, erros de compilação, sintaxe etc. Ao colocar zero isso é interpretado como false ou seja não vai exibir nenhum erro quando eles acontecerem.

Para exibir todos os tipos de erros passe -1.

A lista de contantes os leveis de erro está na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Comment: Obrigada rray eu não encontrei essa informação em lugar nenhum que ao colocar zero é interpletado como false, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @sol25lua a informação está implícita na última frase, antes das notas dos usuários, onde explica que a função opera sobre *bitmasks* e operadores *bit-a-bit*.  Se souber como funcionam esses operadores, entenderá o porquê do zero desabilitar todas as mensagens.

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação informa sim.

> Exemplo #1 Exemplos error_reporting()
>
> ```
> <?php
>     //Turn off all error reporting
>     error_reporting(0);
> ```

Comment: Eu não encontrei na documentação o nivel 0, esta na pergunta