# Como faço para pegar um coluna especifica de um arquivo .txt com PHP

Tags: php, txt

Tenho um arquivo txr com varias colunas mas quero pegar somente um valor especifico da primeira. Até agora consegui abrir o arquivo e separar os valores da cabecalho.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
// $delimitador = "/[\t]/";

// Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
$arquivo = fopen ('bases-para-teste/10.txt', 'r');
if($arquivo){
    // Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
    $cabecalho = fgets($arquivo, 1024);
    echo $cabecalho.'<br />';
    while(!feof($arquivo))
    {
        //Mostra uma linha do arquivo
        $linha = fgets($arquivo, 1024);
        echo $linha.'<br />';
    }
    // Fecha arquivo aberto
    fclose($arquivo);
}
```

Eu gostaria d pegar só a coluna nome. O arquivo esta da seguinte forma:

```
Nome    Sobrenome   Cidade
Wesley  Ferreira Costa  São Paulo
Wendel  Ferreira Costa  São Paulo
```

Comment: Como é o formato do .txt?

Comment: Você que dizer como o conteudo esta dentro dele ?

Comment: sim, não precisa ser o arquivo real, apenas um exemplo já esta bom

Comment: Já atualizei o post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Caso se trate de um SDF ou largura fixa

SDF é arquivo delimitado por espaços (e/ou colunas fixas). Neste caso, basta usar o `substr`.

**Sintaxe:**

```
string substr ( string $string , int $inicio[, int $tamanho] )
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
$nome = substr( $linha, 0, 8 );
//                         ^----- largura da coluna
//                      ^-------- posição inicial da coluna
```

**Manual:**

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

### Caso se trate de um arquivo separado por `tab`s ou outro caractere especial:

Neste caso, o `explode` resolve. O caractere `tab` pode ser representado por `chr( 9 )` em PHP, sendo 9 o código ASCII deste (o mesmo em Unicode).

**Sintaxe:**

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
$itens = explode( chr( 9 ), $linha );
$nome = $itens[0];
```

**Manual:**

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php

Comment: Ou então `"\t"` :)

Comment: `chr(9)` ficou bem ao estilo *old school* do Bacco, @Guilh :)

Comment: @bfavaretto imagine, por incrivel que pareça, eu tenho este vicio também xD

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar o `fgetcsv` e para pegar a primeira coluna use `$data[0]`, também é necessário ignorar a primeira linha, que representa apenas os nomes das colunas, deve ficar algo assim:

```
$row = 1;

$nomes = array();

$handle = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'rb');

if ($handle)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== false)
    {
        if ($row === 1) continue; /*ignora a primeira linha*/

        $row++;

        if (isset($data[0])) {
            $nomes[] = $data[0]; //Vai salvando todos nomes na array
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    die('Erro ao ler o arquivo');
}

print_r($nomes);
```

---

> **não use** o `error_reporting(0);`, principalmente em ambiente de desenvolvimento, se ocorrer erros você não vai saber o que esta fazendo de errado e se for ambiente de produção dê uma lida nisto:
>
> - [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Comment: apareceu somente "Array()"

Comment: @wferreiracosta é porque seu .txt esta com algum problema então, adicione depois do `$row++;`  isto `var_dump($data);` e diga o que aparece.

Comment: @wferreiracosta não use o `error_reporting(0);`, principalmente em ambiente de desenvolvimento, se ocorrer erros você não vai saber o que esta fazendo de errado e se for ambiente de produção dê uma lida nisto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635

Comment: @wferreiracosta tem como me enviar o arquivo `bases-para-teste/10.txt`?

Comment: Não posso enviar e regra de negocio, eu já resolvi o problema.