# Cadastro usando PDO, erro 22527?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho esse código PHP abaixo que será executado após o submit do form para cadastro no banco de dados. Se passar pela validação, um novo usuário será criado e feito o HASH e em seguida a inserção no banco de dados!

```
if (input::exists()) {
  if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {


    $validate = new validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
      'nome' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'min' => 2,
        'max' => 50
      ),
      'sexo' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'email' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'min' => 11,
        'max' => 40,
        'unique' => 'dados'
      ),
      'email2' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'matches' => 'email'
      ),
      'senha' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'min' => 6
      ),
      'senha1' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'matches' => 'senha'
      ),
      'cpf' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'tel' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'cel' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'cep' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'rua' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'numero' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'bairro' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'cidade' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'uf' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'instituição' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'nivel' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'curso' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'area' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'turno' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'palestras' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
      'cidade2' => array(
        'required' => true
      ),
    ));

    if ($validation->passed()) {
      $user = new User();

      $salt = Hash::salt(32);

      try {
        $user->create(array(
          'nome' => input::get('nome'),
          'salt' => $salt,
          'data' => input::get('data'),
          'sexo' => input::get('sexo'),
          'email' => input::get('email'),
          'email2' => input::get('email2'),
          'senha' => Hash::make(input::get('senha'), $salt),
          'senha1' => Hash::make(input::get('senha1'), $salt),
          'cpf' => input::get('cpf'),
          'tel' => input::get('tel'),
          'cel' => input::get('cel'),
          'cep' => input::get('cep'),
          'rua' => input::get('rua'),
          'numero' => input::get('numero'),
          'bairro' => input::get('bairro'),
          'cidade' => input::get('cidade'),
          'uf' => input::get('uf'),
          'instituição' => input::get('instituição'),
          'nivel' => input::get('nivel'),
          'curso' => input::get('curso'),
          'area' => input::get('area'),
          'turno' => input::get('turno'),
          'palestras' => input::get('palestras'),
          'cidade2' => input::get('cidade2'),
          'group1' => 1
        ));
      } catch(Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }
    } else{
      foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
        echo $error, '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}


?>
```

Porém um erro está acontecendo, pois sempre que tento fazer o cadastro é executado o `throw new Exception('Teve um problema ao se tentar criar uma conta!');` que está dentro da classe User. Eu verifiquei as classes, e percebi que a query é criada normalmente, porém no terceiro if do código a baixo, a query não é executada, fazendo com que dê erro. Eu pedi para mostrar o erro e aparece o número `22527`

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++; 
                var_dump($this->_query);
            }
        } 


        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else{
            echo error_reporting(E_ALL);
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;


}
```

Alguém sabe oque é esse erro e como resolve-lo? Eu pesquisei a respeito, mas não consegui entender o que é realmente!

Abaixo a classe User:

```
public function __construct($user = null){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function create($fields = array()) {
    if (!$this->_db->insert('dados', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('Teve um problema ao se tentar criar uma conta!');
    }
}
```

}
    ?>

A baixo a função insert():

```
    public function insert($table, $fields = array()){
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = '';
        $x = 1;

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= "', '";
            }

            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`".implode('`, `', $keys)."`) VALUES (".str_repeat ( "?, " , count($keys)-1 )."?)";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Classe Hash:

```
<?php
class Hash {
public static function make($salt = '', $string = '') {
    return hash('sha256', $salt . $string);
}

public static function salt($length) {
    return random_bytes($length);
}

public static function unique() {
    return self::make(uniqid());
}
}
?>
```

Comment: está usando Laravel?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não, na verdade nunca ouvi falar!

Comment: No método `query()` no `else` faça um `print_r($this->_query->errorInfo());` deve mostrar o erro completo.

Comment: @rray Era um problema de sintaxe, eu uma parte do código estava com `ç e acento`. Agora deu certo. Mas gostaria de te perguntar uma coisa, eu sempre tenho problemas em exibir erros, você conhece algum vídeo ou matéria que explica sobre isso?

Comment: Você está fazendo tudo `static` os métodos desse projeto?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim, acho mais fácil por não ter que ficar instanciando um novo objeto. Isso é ruim?

Comment: @ArthurOliveira é ... algumas coisas pode até serem feitas assim, mas, o seu projeto como todo não ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic entendi, vou procurar mais sobre quando usar e quando não e melhorar o código, muito obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Sobre diretiva de erros veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/91). Recomendo que instale o xdebug para acompanhar o fluxo do código com breakpoints e o mais importante se for lançar um exceção ou retornar um erro grava em um log ou se estiver em ambiente de desenvolvimento exiba o erro na tela mas não exiba algo como `deu erro`. Ao acontecer algum problema no código inclua o maior número de detalhes.

Comment: Muito obrigado @rray vou estudar mais sobre o assunto!!