# Mostrar erros na tela

Tags: php

Como mostrar todos os erros do php no navegador?
Caso por exemplo dê `erro 500`, como mostrar na página web o por que dele ?

Meu questionamento surgiu pois não tenho acesso ao log de erro gerado pelo servidor. Somente ao que é mostrado na tela, surgiu um erro "cabeludo" e o log ajudaria se eu conseguisse vê-lo, daí a necessidade do detalhamento do quê está errado.

Comment: Ou melhor, [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/5878)