# Enviar dados de um formulário por email

Tags: php, sql

O meu objetivo é realizar um formulário de contacto, onde o utilizador inseria o seu nome, email e mensagem. No momento em que clicasse em "enviar mensagem" eu, sendo administradora, iria receber um email, com os dados do utilizador e com a mensagem correspondida. 
De momento, a mensagem envia, mas envia vazio por exemplo:

```
Responda a:
Nome do Utilizador:
Email do Utilizador
Mensagem do Utilizador:
```

Ao enviar a mensagem ocorre também outro problema que aparece uma nova página, com a mesmo formulário mas sem o css, não sei ao que se deve

```
//Formulário contactos.php

<div class="col-md-7 mb-5 site-animate">
            <form action="index.php?cmd=contform" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="sr-only">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NomeM" placeholder="Nome">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmailMen" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="sr-only">Mensagem</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="Mensagem" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Mensagem">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

```php
//Ficheiro contform.php

<?php
$sql="select * from Mensagem ";
$res=$lig->query($sql);
$lin = $res->fetch_array();


$NomeM = $_POST['NomeM'];
$Email = $_POST['EmailMen'];
$Mensagem = $_POST['Mensagem'];


$email_from = 'admin03@happygreen.pt';

$email_subject = "New Form Submission";

$email_body = "Nome do Utilizador:" .$lin['NomeM']."\n".
"Email do Utilizador:".$lin['EmailMen']."\n".
"Mensagem do Utilizador:".$lin['Mensagem']."\n";


$to = "filipajoao1933@gmail.com";

$headers = "De: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Responda a: ".$lin['EmailMen']."\r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("Location: Contactos/contactos.php");

?>
```

Comment: E qual é o valor da sua variável `$lin`? Atente-se ao verbo **é** e não qual **deveria ser**.

Comment: A variável $lin não tem um valor, é utlizada simplesmente para buscar dados da minha base de dados

Comment: Someone, exatamente. Ela está buscando corretamente os dados? Qual o resultado de `var_dump($lin)`? Quais são as últimas mensagens no log de erro do seu servidor e quais são as configurações de exibição de erro do seu PHP?

Comment: Não me retorna nenhum erro, nem apresenta nenhuma mensagem de erro

Comment: E qual o retorno do `var_dump`? Sobre os erros, verificou o arquivo do log ou somente na tela?

Comment: Nenhum, verifiquei simplesmente na tela, não tenho nenhum arquilo log

Comment: Se `var_dump` não retornou nada, tem algum muito errado aí e talvez por isso está enviando tudo em branco. Se a variável não tem valor, não tem o que enviar no e-mail.

Comment: Aproveite para ler como configurar corretamente seu ambiente de desenvolvimento para exibir devidamente as mensagens de erro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/5878

Comment: Percebi que você está utlizando o Mysqli para busca informações no banco de dados, nesse caso indico que você veja esse tutorial se for o caso.
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php

Você precisa criar a `query`, depois prepara-la para executar, como você não está passando parâmetros, pode pular a parte do `bind_param`, em seguido você precisa da o `execute` e por fim o `fetch`.

Comment: Obrigada, vou tentar!

Comment: Ja analisei o documento e continuo sem saber como corrigir o meu erro

Answer (score 0):

Someone, você está gravando os dados que o usuário inseriu na tabela `Mensagem` do  banco de dados?

Se não sua variável `$email_body` deveria ser assim:

```
$email_body = "Nome do Utilizador:" .$Nome."\n".
              "Email do Utilizador:".$Email."\n".
              "Mensagem do Utilizador:".$Mensagem."\n";
```

e essas linhas de código não tem utilidade alguma:

```
$sql="select * from Mensagem ";
$res=$lig->query($sql);
$lin = $res->fetch_array();
```

Comment: Sim tinha como objetivo guardar os dados inseridos no formulário no bando de dados, daí ter feito o segundo trecho de código que inseriu, de forma que fizesse uma ligação com o bando de dados

Comment: Porque se eu utilizar apenas as váriaveis "$Nome" "$Email" e "$Mensagem" e não fizer uma ligação ao banco de dados, os dados não ficarão guardados

Comment: Acabei de tentar da forma que sugeriu e deu o mesmo erro, não retorna nada

Comment: ok, então vamos analisar com mais calma, você está conseguindo receber as informações do `$_POST` no arquivo `contform.php`?

Comment: Não, não sei porquê