# Trocar versão do Excel em exportação com PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Galera, tenho um código que exporta minha tabela do banco de dados perfeitamente, mas ele exporta isso no excel 97 (2003), alguém sabe alguma maneira de exportar essa tabela em outra versão do excel e o arquivo em xlsx em vez de xls? OBS: ja tentei trocar a extensao do arquivo para xlsx e dá erro na hora de abrir o arquivo.

Codigo:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');
error_reporting(0);

 $tabela = '<table border="1">';
 $tabela .= '<tr>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Codigo Prova</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Nome</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Supervisor</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Local</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Data</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 1</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 2</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 3</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 4</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 5</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 6</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 7</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 8</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 9</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Questao 10</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Aprovado ou Reprovado</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Prova</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Numero Acertos</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '<td><b>Numero Erros</b></td>';
 $tabela .= '</tr>';

$result                 = "SELECT * FROM provas";
$result_busca           = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
$contar                 = mysqli_num_rows($row_busca);

while($row_busca = mysqli_fetch_array($result_busca)){
    $tabela .= '<tr>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['cd_prova'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['nome'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['supervisor'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['local'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['data'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao1'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao2'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao3'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao4'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao5'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao6'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao7'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao8'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao9'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['questao10'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['status_aluno'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['tipo_prova'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['numero_acertos'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '<td>'.$row_busca['numero_erros'].'</td>';
    $tabela .= '</tr>';
}
$tabela .= '</table>';

$arquivo = 'prova.xls';

header ('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/x-msexcel');
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");
echo $tabela;
?>
```

Comment: Trocar a extensão do arquivo não modifica realmente o seu tipo, se quer alterar o formato do arquivo deve estudar como ele funciona e adaptar seu código com as diferenças em relação ao atual. Você também pode usar alguma biblioteca que facilite esse processo

Comment: Isto não é EXCEL é um HTML que por coincidencia tem um razoavel suporte nos programas de Office como MSExcel, mas não é de fato excel, nem XLS nem XLSX, é apenas HTML, então não tem versão. Não adianta por uma extensão e acreditar que o conteúdo vá mudar, a extensão é só um facilitador para os sistemas operacionais, como outro exemplo não adiantaria renomear um PNG para  JPG não vai tornar a imagem no formato "JPEG" (me refiro ao conteudo)

Answer (score 1):

**Isto não é EXCEL**, é um HTML que por coincidência tem um razoável suporte nos programas de Office como MSExcel, mas não é de fato excel, nem XLS e nem XLSX, é apenas HTML, então não tem versão.

Não adianta por uma extensão e acreditar que o conteúdo vá mudar, a extensão é só um facilitador para os sistemas operacionais, como outro exemplo não adiantaria renomear um PNG para JPG não vai tornar a imagem no formato "JPEG" (me refiro ao conteúdo).

Se você estiver usando `Composer` (**somente "se" estiver usando**), pode experimentar o composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Instale na pasta do projeto que **JÁ USA composer (se estiver de fato usando)** isto:

```
 composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

Então seu documento deve ficar + ou - assim:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Codigo Prova');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Nome');

...

$i = 1;

while($row_busca = mysqli_fetch_array($result_busca)){
    ++$i; //Incrementa a variavel para ter A2, A3, A4, A5, etc

    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $i, $row_busca['cd_prova']);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $i, $row_busca['nome']);

    ... Demais células aqui ...
}

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$arquivo = 'prova.xlsx';

header ('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header ('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"");

//Envia para o OUTPUT do PHP e posteriormente resolvido pelo SAPI
$writer->save("php://output");
```

Não é fácil criar um arquivo XLSX, então fora essa lib até existem outras soluções, mas nem sei se realmente são confiáveis para uso, nem tenho como citar porque não usei outras.

---

### Extra, não use error_reporting(0); incorretamente

Não é que não deva usar `error_reporting`, o problema é usar achando que serve para apenas sumir com os erros do output, mas isso é um problema, na verdade sentando `0` ele faz bem mais que isso, o ideal seria setar no php.ini da hospesagem `display_errors=Off`, mas isso já deve estar definido, e se for local é de preferencia que os erros sempre estejam ligados, isso porque você deve sempre corrigir todos antes de enviar pra produção, recomendo que leia:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)