# Como separar resultados obtidos LoadHTML

Tags: php, dom

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.zerozero.pt/edicao.php?id_edicao=135716';
$str = '';

$html = file_get_contents($url);

//debug purposes
//$html = '<div id="pagina">foo</div>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
@$doc->loadHTML( $html );

$div = $doc->getElementById( 'edition_table' );



    $str = $div->nodeValue;


echo $str;

?>
```

Este código pega todos os dados da tabela classificativa do site: https://www.zerozero.pt/edicao.php?id_edicao=135716

E retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele retorna me os valores todos, porém eu pretendia separar cada valor obtido por um espaço.
Ou seja separar cada valor que ele puxa para conseguir deferenciar:

Exemplo:
P J V E D GM GS DG 1 Nacional 50 24 etc...

Queria fazer com que o meu codigo retornasse assim.

Como poderei fazer?

Comment: SE já esta usando DOM por que usar EXPLODE? Usa o DOM pra pegar o TR e depois pra pegar o TD.

Comment: Outra coisa, não use o error_reporting com 0, não é pra ocultar erros, por falar nisso nem erros deveriam aparecer, se aparece é pq tem coisa errada, recomendo que leia: [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Comment: Como seria no caso com o DOM?

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php ou aprenda XPath, ps: sem querer fazer jabá, em meu FW eu criei um conversor de CSS Selector para XPath para usar com DOM do PHP: https://github.com/inphinit/inphinit/wiki/QuerySelector-%28seletores-CSS%29-com-PHP#lendo-uma-p%C3%A1gina-externa, claro que já deve ter começado um projeto em php puro ou outro framework, mas é apenas uma indicação.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta, já o fiz so com o DOM, porem continuo sem conseguir fazer o que pretendo...

Comment: Teste seu código seguidas vezes e verá que o retorno é vazio. Me parece que o site de onde está tentando puxar os dados faz verificação reCaptcha. Isto significa que sem validação reCaptcha, a tabela não é carregada pelo `getElementById( 'edition_table' )`.

Comment: Ou ele usa cookie. Sem cookie ele tenta fazer a verificação reCaptcha para evitar isso que vc está tentando fazer.

Comment: Testei o codigo cerca de 50x seguidas e não obtive esse problema, não sei se tenha a haver com a localização...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver este problema utilizando o **DOMDocument** desta forma, use `getElementsByTagName` para buscar a tag `table`,`th` e `td`:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.zerozero.pt/edicao.php?id_edicao=135716';


$Array = [];
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
@$doc->loadHTML( $html );

$div = $doc->getElementById( 'edition_table' );

$table = $div->getElementsByTagName('table');

$ths = $table[0]->getElementsByTagName('th');
foreach($ths as $th):
  $Array[] = $th->nodeValue;
endforeach;

$tds = $table[0]->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($tds as $td):
  $Array[] = $td->nodeValue;
endforeach;

print_r($Array);
```

Segue o **repl** dele funcionando:
https://repl.it/@KleberOliveira/Como-separar-resultados-obtidos-LoadHTML

Comment: Perfeito. é isso mesmo que precisava! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia Gonçalo!

Um Amigo aqui do Site fez uma pergunta parecida, talvez resolva o seu problema...

Foi proposto a seguinte solução:

```
function tdrows($elements)
{
    $str = "";
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $str .= $element->nodeValue . ", ";
    }

    return $str;
}

function getdata()
{
    $contents = "<table><tr><td>Row 1 Column 1</td><td>Row 1 Column 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 2 Column 1</td><td>Row 2 Column 2</td></tr></table>";
    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($contents);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($items as $node) {
        echo tdrows($node->childNodes) . "<br />";
    }
}

getdata();
```

Referencia: [HTML Table to PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449116/html-table-to-php-array)

Abraço.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/270988)

Comment: Obrigado pelo informativo veroneseComS. Irei editar a resposta.